# JTable not getting data from Vector

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem with my JTable: it is seemingly emty and not getting any data from the objects Vector i pass to it. I checked the related topics but sadly i dont find any reason for this issue, and almost the same code actually worked for me once.
For further testing I create objects on a button click, add them into my Vector and then try to refresh the table. Printlns show that the objects actually are added to the Vector, but the table is still empty. I assume, the problem must be somewhere in the table code.
I post my test class and the related ones and hope you can help me.

The test class:

```
    public class TEST_Table extends JFrame {

        private PPControl ppc;
        private EntryFilePM epm;

        private JTable entryTable;
        private JPanel entryTablePanel;

        private JButton addButton;
        private JButton saveButton;
        private JButton loadButton;
        private JPanel buttonsPanel;

        private JLabel kursl;
        private JTextField kurst;

        private JLabel cnumberl;
        private JTextField cnumbert;

        private JLabel namel;
        private JTextField namet;

        private JLabel datel;
        private JTextField datet;

        private JLabel addressl;
        private JTextField addresst;

        private JLabel pdatestl;
        private JTextField pdatestt;

        private JLabel pdateendl;
        private JTextField pdateendt;

        private JLabel roadl;
        private JTextField roadt;

        private JLabel studyfl;
        private JTextField studyft;

        private JLabel naprl;
        private JTextField naprt;

        private JLabel ratingl;
        private JTextField ratingt;

        private JLabel averagel;
        private JTextField averaget;

        private JLabel profl;
        private JTextField proft;

        private JLabel pbasel;
        private JTextField pbaset;

        private JLabel homel;
        private JTextField homet;

        private JPanel horriblePanel;

        private JButton saveEntryButton;
        private JButton cancelEntryButton;

        private JPanel entryButtonsPanel;

        private JPanel entryEditPanel;

        int idCounter = 1;


        public static void main(String[] args) throws EntryExistsException {
            try {
                new TEST_Table();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public int getIdCounterNext(){
            return idCounter++;
        }   

        public TEST_Table() throws IOException, EntryExistsException {
            super("TEST");
            ppc = new PPControl();
            initialize();
        }

        private void initialize() {
            setSize(1200,800);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            createEntryTable();
            createButtonsPanel();
            createEntryTab();
            add(entryTablePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(entryEditPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.pack();

        }

        private void createEntryTable() {
            final Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>();
            columns.add("Std");
            columns.add("Contr #");
            columns.add("Name");

            columns.add("Birth dt");
            columns.add("Address");
            columns.add("Pr date start");

            columns.add("Pr date end");
            columns.add("Road");
            columns.add("Std form");

            columns.add("№ way");
            columns.add("Rating");
            columns.add("Avrg");

            columns.add("Prof");
            columns.add("Pr base");
            columns.add("Home");

            final EntryTableModel entryModel = new EntryTableModel(ppc.giveAllEntry(), columns);
            entryTable = new JTable();
            entryTable.setModel(entryModel);
            entryTable.setShowGrid(true);
    //      entryTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    //      entryTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new TableSelectionListener());
            JScrollPane entryScrollPane = new JScrollPane(entryTable);
            entryTablePanel = new JPanel();
            entryTablePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            entryTablePanel.add(entryScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            entryTablePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
        }

        private void createButtonsPanel() {
            addButton = new JButton("Add");
            saveButton = new JButton("Save");
            saveButton.addActionListener(new ButtonsListener());
            loadButton = new JButton("Load");
            loadButton.addActionListener(new ButtonsListener());

            buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            buttonsPanel.add(addButton);
            buttonsPanel.add(saveButton);
            buttonsPanel.add(loadButton);

        }

        private void createEntryTab(){
            JLabel kursl = new JLabel ("kurs");
            kurst = new JTextField();

//otherlabels/tfields

            JLabel ratingl = new JLabel("rating.double");
            ratingt = new JTextField();

            JLabel averagel = new JLabel("average.double");
            averaget = new JTextField();

            JLabel profl = new JLabel("profession");
            proft = new JTextField();

            JLabel pbasel = new JLabel("prak.base");
            pbaset = new JTextField();

            JLabel homel = new JLabel("home");
            homet = new JTextField();

            horriblePanel = new JPanel();
            JScrollPane horribleScrollPane = new JScrollPane(horriblePanel);
            horriblePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,2));
    //      horriblePanel.add(horribleScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            horriblePanel.add(kursl);
            horriblePanel.add(kurst);

//other labels/tfields
            horriblePanel.add(homel);
            horriblePanel.add(homet);

            saveEntryButton = new JButton("Save");
            saveEntryButton.addActionListener(new ButtonsListener());
            cancelEntryButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            entryButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
            entryButtonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            entryButtonsPanel.add(saveEntryButton);
            entryButtonsPanel.add(cancelEntryButton);

            entryEditPanel = new JPanel();
            entryEditPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            entryEditPanel.add(horriblePanel);
            entryEditPanel.add(entryButtonsPanel);

        }

        class TableSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int rowIndex = -1;
                if (e.getSource().equals(entryTable.getSelectionModel())
                        && entryTable.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                    rowIndex = entryTable.convertRowIndexToModel(entryTable
                            .getSelectedRow());
                    EntryTableModel em = (EntryTableModel) entryTable.getModel();
                    Entry entry = em.giveEntryInRow(rowIndex);
                }
            }
        }

        class ButtonsListener implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ae) {
                if(ae.getSource().equals(addButton)){

                }
                if (ae.getSource().equals(saveButton)){
                    try {
                        epm.exportTable(entryTable);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(ae.getSource().equals(loadButton)){
                    try {
                        epm.importTable("C:/test.xls");
                    } catch (BiffException | IOException | ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (ae.getSource().equals(saveEntryButton)) {
                    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
                    int studyYear = 23;// Integer.parseInt(kurst.getText());
                    int contractNumber = getIdCounterNext();
                    contractNumber++;// Integer.parseInt(cnumbert.getText());
                    String stname = "Uano";// namet.getText();
                    Date birthDate = c.getTime();
                    // birthDate = epm.convertToDate(datet.getText());

                    String address = "abc asd fg 123";// addresst.getText();
                    Date practiceDateStart = c.getTime();
                    // practiceDateStart = epm.convertToDate(pdatestt.getText());

                    Date practiceDateEnd = c.getTime();
                    // practiceDateEnd = epm.convertToDate(pdateendt.getText());
                    String railway = "bad road";// roadt.getText();
                    String studyForm = "bad form";// studyft.getText();
                    int directionNumber = 1232; // =
                                                // Integer.parseInt(naprt.getText());
                    double rating = 3.4;// Double.parseDouble(ratingt.getText());
                    double average = 4.5;// Double.parseDouble(averaget.getText());
                    String profession = "fcki";// proft.getText();
                    String practiceBase = "fckh";// pbaset.getText();
                    String inhabitation = "fckf2";// homet.getText();
                    try {
                        ppc.addEntry(studyYear, contractNumber, stname, birthDate,
                                address, practiceDateStart, practiceDateEnd, railway,
                                studyForm, directionNumber, rating, average,
                                profession, practiceBase, inhabitation);

                        for (Entry e : ppc.giveAllEntry()) {
                        System.out.println(e.getContractNumber());
                        System.out.println(e.getName());
                        System.out.println(e.getBirthDate());
                    }
                    final EntryTableModel em = (EntryTableModel) entryTable.getModel();
                    System.out.println("a");
                    em.setDataVector(ppc.giveAllEntry());
                    entryTable.updateUI();
                        System.out.println("b");

                    } catch (EntryExistsException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                        }
                }

            }
        }
```

The TableModel class:

```
public class EntryTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private Vector<Entry> entryList;

    public EntryTableModel(final Vector<Entry> eList, final Vector<String> columnNames) {
        super();
        this.columnIdentifiers = columnNames;
        entryList = (Vector<Entry>) eList;
        this.setDataVector(eList);
    }

    void setDataVector(final Vector<Entry> eList) {
        final Vector<Vector<String>> rows = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (Entry e : eList) {
            final Vector<String> entryAsVector = new Vector<String>();
            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getStudyYear());
            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getContractNumber());
            entryAsVector.add(e.getName());

            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getBirthDate());
            entryAsVector.add(e.getAddress());
            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getPracticeDateStart());

            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getPracticeDateEnd());
            entryAsVector.add(e.getRailway());
            entryAsVector.add(e.getStudyForm());

            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getDirectionNumber());
            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getRating());
            entryAsVector.add("" + e.getAverage());

            entryAsVector.add(e.getProfession());
            entryAsVector.add(e.getPracticeBase());
            entryAsVector.add(e.getInhabitation());
        }
        this.setDataVector(rows, columnIdentifiers);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    public Entry giveEntryInRow(int row) {
        return entryList.get(row);
    }
```

The functions that give my objects Vector

```
public class EntryControl {
    private Vector <Entry> entryList = new Vector <Entry> ();
    public void addEntry(Entry e) throws EntryExistsException{
        if (entryList.contains(e))
            throw new EntryExistsException(e, "");
        else
            entryList.add(e);
    }
    public Vector<Entry> listAllEntry(){
        return entryList;
    }
//reference in main control class
    public Vector<Entry> giveAllEntry(){
        return entryControl.listAllEntry();
    }
```

Output:
http://i57.tinypic.com/125geac.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setDataVector` method, you are not adding anything to `rows`.  You probably want to add this line:

```
rows.add(entryAsVector);
```

You could have uncovered this problem yourself if you had checked the value of `rows` when you pass it to this.setDataVector, either by adding a print statement or by using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your TableModel class is a bit schizophrenic in that it extends DefaultTableModel, a class that already has its own data nucleus and yet despite this, it holds its own data nucleus, entryList, ignoring the one that the DefaultTableModel parent has. You need to do one of two things: Either use your entryList field and extend AbstractTableModel, or get rid of it and be sure to pass your data into the parent DefaultTableModel's super constructor call.